# mysql Explain - how do I see the result on webpage?

Tags: mysql, explain

I add EXPLAIN in front of my query in my SQL string

I'm on the web page of the web site running on local server

But how do I get to see the output of the `EXPLAIN` ?

Echo and print_r both return: Resource id #33

How do I get to see those funky little SQL diagrams?

Comment: Execute the query in PHPMYADMIN.

Comment: ok thanks .. that works - not sure why my question gets a -1 though

Comment: I didn't vote the question down, but downvotes are used to indicate that "*this question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful*".  See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Comment: I run EXPLAIN in PHPMyAdmin SQL and get the table `id  select_type  table  type  possible_keys  key  key_len  ref  rows  Extra ` returned, What funky little SQL diagrams are you talking about? I want to see it.

Answer (score 0):

I found that on the html page you can do:

$row_exp=mysql_fetch_array($resource);

print_r($row_exp);

by funky tables I just meant the little things broken into aligned boxes with dashed borders

phpmyAdmin does this BUT the html page solution above, using print_r does not, so only good for basic use. I'm sure someone knows the full code to show it in tabular layout on a web page...